# How to pass in my current window and drag it using a class method in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

My window drag is not working.
here is my code :

```
    public WindowsButtonsVm(Window currentWindow)
    {
        _currentWindow = currentWindow;
    }

    public void MoveWindow(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        try
        {
            // Begin dragging the window

            _currentWindow.DragMove();


        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

        }
    }
```

Current window is my main window that I passed in.

my class WindowsButtonsVm  inherits from from this class:

```
 public class ViewModelBase : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

when the user does left mouse down on my header button is I called this :

```
 private void HeaderBackgroundBtn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       
        WindowsButtonsVm WindowBtn = (WindowsButtonsVm) WindowButtons1.DataContext;

        WindowBtn.MoveWindow(e);
        
    }
```

So I feel like I did everything right, but I am getting this error:

```
"Can only call DragMove when primary mouse button is down."
```

Comment: I'd start by removing the `try`/`catch (Exception err)` - just write the code and don't wrap it in an inane error handler.

Comment: @ Enigmativity that is how I am able to see the error message in debug mode and removing it only makes the program crash. I am not sure what your point is

Comment: Let your program crash - then fix the issue so it doesn't crash. Exception handling should only be done for ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle.

Comment: @Spencer I guess you are actually capturing `Button.Click` or other events rather than  `Button.MouseDown` event because that event is not usally capturable.

Comment: You must implement dragging in the code-behind of the particular Window. Never handle UI in the view model.

Comment: All, I am trying to make a Reusable  header bar control, that I can drop into any project.  I was hoping to have all the code-behind done in the control and  I could make a Reusable NuGet. But then I learned that I could  not use   DragMove() in a control. I have a Viewmodel that deals with all my widow resizing, so I was hoping I could just that same Viewmodel for my Drag.

Comment: You should not do anything UI related in your view model. Never. View model doee not resize anything nor does it care for or participates in any layout related logic. UI is taboo for the view model . Violating this rule will lead to a bad application design which will get more severe the bigger your project becomes over time. In OO programming we can introduce a base class like `DraggableWindow : Window` to make core functionality reusable.

Comment: @ BioncCode,  Ok I will not do it that  way then. I  really didn't know that was a rule.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement dragging in the code-behind of the particular `Window`. Never handle UI in the view model.

```cs
partial class MyWindow : Window
{
  protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

    // Begin dragging the window
    DragMove();
  }
}
```

Or to allow dragging the `Window` by clicking any child element, simply handle the tunneling event version:

```cs
partial class MyWindow : Window
{
  protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

    // Begin dragging the window
    DragMove();
  }
}
```

Comment: From their code it looks like they want to move the Window via holding the mouse down on a Button control in which case subscribing to the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event of the Button is correct. Not in the ViewModel of course with MVVM.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are correct and if this would make any sense. However, handling the tunneling event would allow to drag the Window by clicking any contained element. WPF input events are all routed events. There is usually no need to deal with the event source explicitly if the listener is a parent element. In this case, Window is the parent that would listen to mouse events raised by its child elements.